# PHP, print_r($_SESSION) doesn't show its content?

Tags: php, session

I want to see the content of the the array $_SESSION with the command print_r($_SESSION) but what I get is just the following output:

```
Array ()
```

what am I missing ?

thanks

Comment: yes it's empty! The more pertinent question is why is it empty...

Comment: Did you call `session_start`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you call `session_start()` at the top of all the pages you wish to use the session.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
<?php

session_start();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note** `<?php session_start(); ?>` must be called before any other output is sent to the browser.

#### index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['hello'] = 'world';
print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

#### Output

```
Array (
  [hello] => world
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are missing.

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually Its Printing The Session Variables But You Have Not Set Any Before Therefore The Array Returned By print_r($_SESSION) is Empty Try Setting The Variables First and Then Print Them.

Remember that session_start(); should always be first line.