# Store checkbox in PHP Session and echo it

Tags: php, forms, variables, session, checkbox

I'm trying to store a form of checkcboxes into a session variable so I can echo it out on a different page. 
EXAMPLE:
User picks first two checkboxes on page 1. Page redirects to page 2 where "apple" and "banana" is printed.

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="crate[]" value="apple" type="checkbox">
    <input name="crate[]" value="banana" type="checkbox">
    <input name="crate[]" value="potato" type="checkbox">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: yes, you are right ... `print_r($_POST['crate']);` then `$_SESSION['checkboxes'] = $_POST['crate'];`

Comment: Are you trying to store which checkboxes where checked by the user, or are you trying to store the HTML code of this form? Rather unclear what exactly you mean; and also, what the actual problem is. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: if you just wanna save data from page to page you have many options (with pros and cons): cookies, localStorage, DB (directly or thru sessions). Please be more explicit. Of course I guess you wanna save selected checkbox data.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm guessing it's a very simple solution.

Comment: Where's the code to write something to the session? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I don't have any code for the session. That's what i'm asking for, i'm asuming it isn't more than 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

After submission of the form, You need to check whether post not empty then assign it in the session variable

```
$_SESSION['VARIABLE_NAME'] = empty($_POST['crate']) ? [] : $_POST['crate'];
```

In the second page, also check session variable exist and not empty

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['VARIABLE_NAME'])){
   print_r($_SESSION['VARIABLE_NAME']);
}
```

**Note**:- Don't forget to write `session_start();` at top of the page and check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages).

Comment: It still doesn't print. When i take the print_r line out of the if statement, it simply prints an empty array. I'm not sure why it doesn't pass the values into the array in page 1

Comment: Have you print  `$_POST['crate']`?? If it contains value then `$_SESSION['VARIABLE_NAME']` must be set. check this link also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181149/php-print-r-session-doesnt-show-its-content

Comment: If i print $_POST['crate'] on page 2 it gives me an error. If i print_r($_SESSION) it prints an empty array inside of VARIABLE_NAME. It don't think it get's passed into the array correctly on page 1

Comment: I hope you have set the correct form action. check this link1: https://www.guru99.com/php-forms-handling.html and link2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184670/html-php-form-input-as-array